# Can't get the view updated, even though the model is already updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

**This is my XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="NoteBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteBox"
    Title="NoteBox">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NoteOctaveConverter x:Key="NoteOctaveConverter"/>
    <local:DottedNoteConverter x:Key="DottedNoteConverter"/>
    <local:NoteEnumerationConverter x:Key="NoteEnumerationConverter"/>
    <local:NoteAccidentalConverter x:Key="NoteAccidentalConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="OemPeriod" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Blank"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D0" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="Rest"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N1"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D2" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N2"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D3" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N3"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D4" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N4"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D5" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N5"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D6" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N6"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="D7" Command="{Binding KeyboardHotkeyCommand}" CommandParameter="N7"/>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Background="GreenYellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource NoteAccidentalConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Note, Converter={StaticResource NoteEnumerationConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
             BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource NoteOctaveConverter}, ConverterParameter=TOP, Mode=OneWay}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
             BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource NoteOctaveConverter}, ConverterParameter=BOT, Mode=OneWay}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
             BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Dot, Converter={StaticResource DottedNoteConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**This is XAML.CS**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new NoteBoxViewModel();
    }
}
```

**And this is my ModelView**

```
public class NoteBoxViewModel
{
    public MusicalNotation MusicalNotation { get; set; }
    public ICommand KeyboardHotkeyCommand { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public NoteBoxViewModel()
    {
        MusicalNotation = new MusicalNotation();
        KeyboardHotkeyCommand = new KeyboardHotkeyCommand(this);
        IsSelected = true;

        //Initialization testing
        MusicalNotation.Note = Notes.N1;
        MusicalNotation.Dot = 1;
        MusicalNotation.Octave = -2;
        MusicalNotation.Accidental = Accidentals.Flattened;
    }
}
```

Even though the model is updated, but the View isn't when input using the `InputBindings`. Input detection is working properly and the model is updated properly. The converter also works well, otherwise, the initialization testing won't visualize anything too. (The data from initialization testing showed perfectly).

My guess is somewhere on the binding. But I can't find any.

Thanks.

Note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  have to Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

```
 public class NoteBoxViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
   //here an example 
        public MusicalNotation MusicalNotation
    { 
     get{
         return _musicalNotation;
        } 
      set{ _musicalNotation =Value;
             // by using [CallerMemberName]  you  don't  need to pass the name of the method  (this only available in .net 4.5 )
            NotifyPropertyChanged();}
          }        

        public NoteBoxViewModel()
        {
            MusicalNotation = new MusicalNotation();
            KeyboardHotkeyCommand = new KeyboardHotkeyCommand(this);
            IsSelected = true;

            MusicalNotation.Note = Notes.N1;
            MusicalNotation.Dot = 1;
            MusicalNotation.Octave = -2;
            MusicalNotation.Accidental = Accidentals.Flattened;


        }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how should I code `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` which is implemented from the `INotifyPropertyChanged`? And also, can you elaborate the purpose of `private void NotifyPropertyChanged()` and how it is used? Thanks.

Comment: take a look  now I updated my code the NotifyPropertyChanged() is just to  invoke the method PropertyChanged

Comment: There are 4 errors : **1.** `The event 'NoteBox.NoteBoxViewModel.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=` and **2.** `'NoteBox.NoteBoxViewModel.PropertyChanged': event property must have both add and remove accessors` and **3.** `The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and **4.** `The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: at wiich  line you  got this

Comment: Oops sorry, There are only 2 errors : **1.** `The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and **2.** `The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` all of them is on `CallerMemberName` of your method.

Comment: which version  of .net you  are using

Comment: have u added  this to  your code using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55925/discussion-between-moses-aprico-and-k-b).

Comment: Alright then. The compiler error's gone when I switched to 4.5. But there isn't any change happened (still got the old problem)

Comment: that's expected as  you  have to do the something with MusicalNotation

Comment: You mean the class? Or the property in the ViewModel?

Comment: I mean all the class MusicalNotation should Implements  the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Really? So all of my models should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then should have `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method, event, and call it from each of the `get` property?